# Why an application would create 31 "GC task thread" in one Solaris box while only 2 in another box

Tags: multithreading, memory, garbage-collection, jvm, solaris

I saw in one application (java) which has irregular memory usage in a Solaris box. When I took a thread dump, I saw there were 31 "GC task thread"...

This is very strange as in other Solaris box, same application only had 2 "GC task thread".

Wondered if anybody know, under which circumstance, the jvm will create so many GC task threads and could this cause memory issue?

Any ideas is appreciated.

Some more background on my case:
Each time I will have two similar Java applications running at the same time in same box. I will keep sending requests to application A , and no request to application B. So, app B should be in-active. And it is alway "sleep" when using prstat.

Strange thing is, in one Solaris box, app B keeps consuming memory while app A is processing request. And in app B's thread dump, I can see 31 GC task threads.
And in another Solaris box, app B is normal, the memory is normal and only 2 GC task threads.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi, could you some more details? Perhaps, which JVM and what version are using, what are the JVM parameters, how many processors does each machine have. You might also want to run with `-verbose:gc` to get more details on what the GC is doing.

Comment: thanks @haggai_e for helping. It turns out that the jvm was busying allocating and releasing memory due to very high request load. I should look into the heap dump or use jconsole (jvisualvm) earlier.

Answer (score 3):

The GC task thread is related with the parallel garbage collector behaviour.
The value of number of parallel GC threads are defined by the

```
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=n
```

command line parameter. In the documentation of Java hotspot VM, it says:

> -XX:ParallelGCThreads=n
>
> Sets the number of threads used during parallel phases of the garbage
> collectors. The default value varies with the platform on which the
> JVM is running.

(see: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html)

The documentation does not explicitly state, but the default value varies with the number of processors/cores the platform has, and I think the number is equal to the number of CPU cores.

So far, this was the answer of "why JVM creates that many GC task threads.

Does this cause any memory issues? The answer is no. In fact, each of the GC threads will have very low memory footprints, and thus they are not expected to cause any considerable memory issues. However, you may want to finetune the number of garbage collection threads by using the parameter described above.